# NIST(National Institute of Standards and Technology) library for iOS

Tags: ios, linker

I downloaded some code which contains some source code and some txt files.

The Read me or Installation file says following,

---

```
                NBIS Open Source Software Installation Guide
                          (For LINUX and MAC OSX)
               ----------------------------------------------
```

Step 1:
        Run the following command to setup your build environment:

```
    ./setup.sh <TARGET INSTALLATION DIR> [--without-X11]
             [--STDLIBS] [--without-OPENJP2] [--32 | --64]

    <TARGET INSTALLATION DIR> is replaced by the specific directory path
    where you want to install the NBIS applications, libraries,
    pre-computed runtime data and manuals.

    Option Usage :
         --without-X11          Build without X11 support.
         --STDLIBS              Build without JASPER, OpenJP2 and PNG
                                image format support.
         --without-OPENJP2      Build without OpenJP2 image format 
                                support.
         --32                   Build on 32-bit architecture machine.
                                (Only applicable for LINUX build.
                                 If you are compiling on a 64-bit 
                                 machine, please have the proper
                                 32-bit libraries installed.)
         --64                   Build on 64-bit architecture machine
                                (Only applicable for LINUX build.)

    Example:
    > ./setup.sh /SRC/NBIS/Main --32
```

Step 2:
        Run the following commands to build "NBIS":

> make config
>   make it

Step 3:
        Run the following command to install NBIS executables into the
         directory:

> make install LIBNBIS=[yes|no]

Step 4: (OPTIONAL)
        Run the following command, if you want to generate a list of
        API supported in NBIS.

> make catalog

Note:   If you enable the `"LIBNBIS=no"` option during make install, 
        it will create the following libraries:

> ```
>             liban2k.a libclapck.a libfft.a libioutil.a libmindtct.a 
>             libnfseg.a libpcautil.a libutil.a libbozorth3.a libf2c.a 
>             libihead.a libjpegb.a libmlp.a libopenjp2.a libpcax.a 
>             libwsq.a libcblas.a libfet.a libimage.a libjpegl.a libnfiq.a 
>             libpca.a libpng.a libz.a
> ```

```
    If you enable the "LIBNBIS=yes" option during make install, it will 
    combine all the libraries listed above and build libnbis.a.
```

Can I use the library build using above in my xCode project for iOS.

Thank You,
Subhash

Comment: yes you can use the .a library in your project

Comment: @VarunNaharia:Thank you for quick turn around.I have used libraries in iOS but those libraries were specifically built for iOS and were having the proper lib structure which involved /Include and the header files which need to be exposed to outer space.This thing only builds .a. will that work?

Comment: yes there are many library with .a extension that we use in our project

Comment: @VarunNaharia:The .a library is not built for arm64 architecture,then how we can use it?Any Idea?